# javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :vfw://0

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting error in the following code:

```
private void initCamera() throws IOException, NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException
{
    MediaLocator ml = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");
    player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
    this.tbCamera.add(player.getVisualComponent());
    player.start();
}
```

Following is the trace:

```
Jul 31, 2017 3:17:05 PM attendancemanagement.Student <init>
SEVERE: null
javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :vfw://0
at javax.media.Manager.createPlayerForContent(Manager.java:1412)
at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:417)
at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:553)
at attendancemanagement.Student.initCamera(Student.java:67)
at attendancemanagement.Student.<init>(Student.java:52)
at attendancemanagement.Student.main(Student.java:294)
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171651/webcam-cannot-find-a-player-for-vfw-0) didn't help me.

Comment: Processor ip = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(new MediaLocator("vfw://0"));
ip.setContentDescriptor(new FileTypeDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

try
{
player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ip.getDataOutput());
player.start();

Comment: media location may be wrong "vfw://0" please cross check

Comment: Got the link here, if it helps you. https://community.oracle.com/thread/1279090?start=0

Comment: hi i tried all method you guys mentioned above. nothing worked for me... :(